# Combine information into a department vector

Tags: sas

I want to summarize a dataset by creating a vector that gives information on what departments the id is found in.  For example,

```
data test;
    input id dept $;
    datalines;
    1 A
    1 D
    1 B
    1 C
    2 C
    3 D
    4 A
    5 C
    5 D
    ;
run;
```

I want

```
id dept_vect
1  1111
2  0010
3  0001
4  1000
5  1001
```

The position of the elements of the dept_vect is organized alphabetically. So a '1' in the first position means that the id is found in deptartment A and a '1' in the second position means that the id is found in department B. A '0' means the id is not found in the department.

I can solve this problem using a brute force approach

```
proc transpose data = test out = test1(drop = _NAME_);
by id;
var dept;
run;

data test2;
  set test1;
  array x[4] $ col1-col4;
  array d[4] $ d1-d4;

  do i = 1 to 4;
        if not missing(x[i]) then do;
              if x[i] = 'A' then d[1] = 1;
                 else if x[i] = 'B' then d[2] = 1;     
                 else if x[i] = 'C' then d[3] = 1;
                 else if x[i] = 'D' then d[4] = 1;
              end;
        else leave;
    end;

  do i = 1 to 4;
       if missing(d[i]) then d[i] = 0;
  end;

  dept_id = compress(d1) || compress(d2) || compress(d3) || compress(d4);

  keep id dept_id;
 run;
```

This works but there are a couple of problems. For col4 to appear, I need at least one id to be found on all departments but that could be fixed by creating a dummy id so that id is found on all departments. But the main problem is that this code is not robust. Is there a way to code this so that it would work for any number of departments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a 1 to get a count variable
2. Transpose using PROC TRANSPOSE
3. Replace missing with 0
4. Use CATT() to create desired results.

   ```
   data have;
   input id dept $;
   count = 1;
   datalines;
   1 A
   1 D
   1 B
   1 C
   2 C
   3 D
   4 A
   5 C
   5 D
   ;
   run;

   proc transpose data=test out=wide prefix=dept; 
   by id;
   id dept;
   var count;
   run;

   data want;
   set wide;
   array _d(*) dept:;
   do i=1 to dim(_d);
         if missing(_d(i)) then _d(i) = 0;
   end;
   want = catt(of _d(*));
   run;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe TRANSREG can help with this.

```
data test;
    input id dept $;
    datalines;
    1 A
    1 D
    1 B
    1 C
    2 C
    3 D
    4 A
    5 C
    5 D
    ;
run;
proc transreg;
   id id;
   model class(dept / zero=none);
   output design out=dummy(drop=dept);
   run;
proc print;
   run;
proc summary nway;
   class id;
   output out=want(drop=_type_) max(dept:)=;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```